# Posicionar icono agregar en mi CardView

Tags: android-studio, xml

estoy trabajando con el diseño de un CardView donde tengo unos TextView para que muestre algunos datos, pero necesito poner un icono “+” para agregarlo a una venta, pero no lo puedo colocar al lado derecho como se muestra en la imagen y centrarlo tanto horizontal como vertical.

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias

> Código de mi avance (icono comentado)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="No Venta"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtVID"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtCodigo"
                            android:text="KD546SD"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtDescrip"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Producto"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:text="$"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtVPrecio"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:text="150.15"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--<ImageView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/imgView"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="40dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="40dp"-->
        <!--android:padding="4dp"-->
        <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_regular"-->
        <!--android:layout_weight="1"/>-->
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Resultado que necesito con el icono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregarle un identificador a tu segundo `Layout` interno para poder alinear el elemento `ImageView`, y agregarle los atributos:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/inter"
```

**Diseño:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/inter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sentiment_very_satisfied" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/inter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="No Venta"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtVID"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                            android:textColor="#000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtCodigo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                            android:text="KD546SD"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtDescrip"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Producto"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:text="$"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtVPrecio"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:text="150.15"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu respuesta.

Comment: @Javierfr de nada, saludos un gusto poder ayudarle.